# How to mock Bugsnag in jest test cases for a react app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, bugsnag

```
Bugsnag.start({
  apiKey: BUGSNAG_KEY,
  plugins: [new BugsnagPluginReact()],
  releaseStage: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  appVersion: APP_VERSION,
})

const ErrorBoundary = Bugsnag.getPlugin('react').createErrorBoundary(React)
```

using  "@bugsnag/js": "^7.11.0", "@bugsnag/plugin-react": "^7.11.0",

trying to do jest.mock("@bugsnag/js") but getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createErrorBoundary' of undefined

Comment: Show the test code. Besides, please provide complete, minimal code

Comment: You probably _shouldn't_ mock Bugsnag - that's an API you don't own. Depending on what you're trying to test, and where that boundary sits, you may either want to encapsulate it in e.g. a function you do own (and which you _can_ easily mock) or simply unit test the components without the error boundary (then have an integration-level test that makes sure the error boundary's own behaviour is appropriate).

Comment: There's a conversation on one of the issues over at the `bugsnag-js` repository on GitHub discussing how you may approach Bugsnag and the `ErrorBoundary` component in your tests: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-js/issues/344#issuecomment-386156305.

It may be worth reviewing that and seeing how you get on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get this working:

```
jest.mock('bugsnag-js', () => (
  () => ({
    use(plugin) {
      const boundary = plugin.init();
      /* you don't want the error boundary to swallow the errors, 
         just want jest to see them and fail the test
      */
      delete boundary.prototype.componentDidCatch;
      return boundary;
    },
  })
));
```